# Add a transparent image on top of a material [duplicate 2]

Tags: materials, shaders

I read the answer on the link on how to add transparent images on top of materials ([Add a transparent image on top of a material](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material) ). This works beautifully in v2.79b.

[image: Node setup in Blender 2.79b]

This technique does not seem to work in Blender 2.80 anymore (I am using the very latest Mac version from Dec 20). The transparent image is also shown on the part of the mesh, which is not UV unwrapped. Is this a bug in v2.80? Or does v2.80 require a different approach?

[image: Node setup in Blender 2.80 beta]

What is really odd is the fact, that if I open in v2.80 a file created in v2.79 created, it shows up correctly.

[image: Blender 2.79b file opened in Blender 2.80 beta]

Thanks for any advice!
Chris

Edits: screenshots and link to blender files added

https://www.dropbox.com/s/4kh40l870lbj96x/Ninja.zip?dl=1

Answer (score 0):

*UPDATED*
I totally misunderstood your problem in my first answer so here is an update. 
Your problem wasnt the transparency obviously, but the UV map itself. 
As I checked your file (ninja28) It was like having two UV maps one over each other or maybe just overlaps on the same channel. I dont know what caused this, but if you did a remapping (even by using the mapping node or unwrapping the mesh again - I did both) it should work fine.

[image]

**And Here is your (edited) file:**
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not solve this issue.

Comment: Ok let me download these files first and I plan let you know in a while :)

Comment: Oh, sorry! I forgot to pack the v2.79 file.

[https://www.dropbox.com/s/z2dwjahx5b51tg5/Ninja.zip?dl=1]